# Why is an interleaver often placed between an outer block code and an inner convolution code?

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding, forward-error-correction, reed-solomon

It seems that when doing FEC with a concatenated-code, an interleaver is often placed between the outer block code and the inner convolution code.  The explanations I've seen say that this is because the convolution decoder often has errors in bursts.

However, if we assume that we're using a Reed-Solomon decoder with 8-bit symbols, then spreading the bursts onto multiple blocks would seem to increase errors rather than decrease them.  What am I missing that explains why this interleaving is good?

Rough idea of the decode and encode process:

- Encode:

$$\boxed{\textrm{Data}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{RS Encoder}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{Interleaver}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{Convolution Encoder}}{\longrightarrow} \boxed{\textrm{Modulator}}$$

- Decode:

$$\boxed{\textrm{Demodulator}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{Convolution Decoder}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{De-interleaver}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{RS Decoder}}{\longrightarrow}\boxed{\textrm{Data}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answers mention, the use of FEC results in post-decoding errors occurring 
in bursts. Indeed, this happens regardless of whether the code is a convolutional code
or a block code.  With a $(n,k)$ block code, the decoder output ($k$ bits)
from the decoding of one 
received word is (hopefully with high probability) completely correct, or it has 
an unknown number of errors in it that can be regarded as a burst error of length $k$.
With a convolutional code, the decoder output is mostly correct as the decoder
finds the correct path through the trellis, but occasionally the decoder's
chosen path *deviates* from the correct path and later *rejoins* the correct 
path during which time there is a burst of errors. In contrast to
block codes, there can be multiple
isolated burst errors (of variable lengths) in a single transmission
using a convolutional code. Also, the number of data bits in a single
transmission is far larger than the typical values of $k$ for a
block code.

The idea behind a concatenated
coding scheme is that with an inner code suited to the physical channel,
and an outer code over a *very large symbol alphabet*, we can make
the burst errors in the inner decoder output look like a *single
symbol error* to the outer code.  This is important because the
outer code should be a very high rate code because the net rate
is product of the inner code rate (more or less determined by
the channel and the link budget) and the outer code rate. 
Unfortunately, outer codes over very large alphabets are very
expensive to implement, and so interleaved Reed-Solomon codes
over smaller alphabets (often GF$(2^8)$ ) are used (with 
interleaving at the symbol
level, as Jim Clay points out). Because of the interleaving, the burst
errors in the inner decoder output become single symbol (byte) errors in the
received words of the interleaved Reed-Solomon code.

All the above is mostly a rehash of what the answers by Bryan and
Jim Clay have already said, but I wish to point out the following.

> Interleaved Reed-Solomon codewords can be decoded much more
>   efficiently and with smaller delay if they are *not* de-interleaved
>   first.

A [Reed-Solomon decoder](http://www.vlsi.csl.uiuc.edu/~shanbhag/publications/sarwt-tvlsi-2001.pdf) that can decode interleaved codewords is different from
the off-the-shelf standard Reed-Solomon
decoders that are available, and the use of such a decoder might not be
feasible if the development team does not have control of this aspect of
the design. But, if such a decoder is used, the de-interleaver
can be moved from the between the inner decoder and outer decoder to
just after the outer decoder. The de-interleaver is also *smaller* since
it has to deinterleave a $K\times L$ array instead of a $N \times L$
array (for a $(N.K)$ Reed-Solomon code interleaved to depth $L$.

> If a *delay-scaled* Reed-Solomon *encoder* is used along with the
>   Reed-Solomon decoder for interleaved codewords described above, the interleaver
>   at the transmitter and the de-interleaver at the receiver
>   can be eliminated entirely.

The output of the delay-scaled
encoder (see also 
[this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/4586217/4594928/04595370.pdf?) 
which is unfortunately behind a paywall)
is a set of *interleaved* Reed-Solomon codewords, but
is *not* the same sequence of bytes that one would get from
doing a standard Reed-Solomon encoding followed by interleaving.
So, no further interleaving is necessary.
The output of the interleaved Reed-Solomon decoder is the
same byte sequence in the same order that went into the *delay-scaled*
Reed-Solomon encoder, and so no de-interleaving is necessary
at the decoder, either.

Comment: The link to the paper doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @JimClay Sorry about that. I have changed the link from my web page to my co-author's web page which seems to work better, but for a clean copy, you might have to access the original behind IEEE's paywall.

Answer (score 1):

Block codes (such as the Reed-Solomon you mentioned) have the ability to detect and correct a certain number of errors that is tied directly to the properties of that code (minimum Hamming distance for example). By passing on burst errors from the inner-channel, this may put too many errors in a single block than the code is capable of correcting. If, however, we spread these errors to multiple block codes, then each respective block code will hopefully have a small number of errors it's capable of correcting. As an example with probably unrealistic numbers (these type of setups are often used with massive convolutional codes), if your block code is capable of correcting 1 error, and you get a burst of 4 errors, then you will have 1 block with 4 errors, 1 block with 3 and 1 block with 1, or 2 blocks with with 2 errors. In all scenarios, we have an uncorrectable error if we don't do any interleaving. However, if we can interleave such that we guarantee bursts of 4 errors will be spread in 4 blocks, then we can correct all errors and all is well.

Comment: Makes sense, but if all you have is one big block on the outside then there's no point, right?  Cause it seems like with Reed-Solomon you can make your block arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

I think the part that you are missing is that the burst of errors out of the convolutional decoder is (or at least should be) a rare event.  Thus, every once in a while there will be a burst of errors, but most of the time there are no errors coming out of the convolutional decoder.

If there wasn't an interleaver whenever a burst of errors occurred one or two blocks (depending on where the burst occurred relative to the block boundaries) would be swamped with errors while their neighbors would have no errors.  The interleaver spreads the errors out so that they are "shared" between many blocks, making them manageable by all the blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jim -- I think I figured out my faulty assumption -- I'm assuming one large block on the outside instead of many smaller blocks.  With one large block the interleaver makes things worse by spreading a bunch of contiguous bad bits across different symbols in a block.

Comment: That's correct, it's multiple smaller blocks.

Comment: Also, the interleaving is done at RS symbol level, not the bit level, so all of the errors in a symbol stay together.